# unable to use create method on collections in backbonejs

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a collection in backbone like this:

```
app.ledgerList=Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: app.ledger,
localStorage:new Store('ledgers')
});

///initializing

app.ledgers=new app.ledgerList();
```

And in one of my views later in app, i have:

```
saveLedger: function(){

    name=$("#ledgerName").val();
    email=$("#ledgerEmail").val();
    address=$("#ledgerAddress").val();
    phone=$("#ledgerPhone").val();
    console.log(app.ledgers.length);
    app.ledgers.create({name:name,email:email,address:address,phone:phone});
}
```

This returns me `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'` on the line `app.ledgers.create({name:name,email:email,address:address,phone:phone})`
What may be the problem?

Comment: Follow-up post: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'localStorage' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423455/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-localstorage-of-undefined)

Comment: The value you are trying to save, they are all valid? 
app.ledgers, can you check to make sure it is a collection at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like at the time you're calling `create()` that `app.ledgers` is no longer a Collection. You should `console.log(app.ledgers)` right above the create() statement.